# MX Grid Lite: image not shown

Tags: image

this is the first time i’m using grid lite (i need it for a gallery)

I’ve the following code

```
<div id="galleria">
          {!-- Grid Lite --}
          {exp:channel:entries channel="galleria"}
            {immagini}

              <img src="{immagine}" />

            {/immagini}         
          {/exp:channel:entries}

</div>
```

where {immagini} is the grid lite’s fieldtype , and {immagine} is the grid lite’s column
but the content not shown

I’m doing something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was a bug in grid lite

today max lazar will fix it